# Archive tables in azure

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have a table storage in Azure where-in one of the tables is growing rapidly and I need to archive the tables for any data older than 90 days. Tried reading online and the only solution I can get online is to use Eventually consistent transactions pattern : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/. Although the document takes an example of an employee table and can help me in achieving my objective, the intention of posting this question is to identify if there is a better solution.

Please note I am very new to Azure so might be missing a very easy step to achieve this.

Regards Tarun

Comment: Where do you wish to archive the data to?

Comment: Also tell us how the data is partitioned in this table especially the PartitionKey you are using.

Comment: We would like to archive the data in a different table

Comment: Regarding partitioning of data, I have sent a query to the owner of the table. Will get back once I have the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide you are referencing is a good source. Note that if you are using Tables for logging data (has a common requirement for archiving older data) then you might want to look at blob storage instead - see the log data pattern in the guide you reference. Btw, AzCopy can also be used to export the data either to a blob or to local file system. See here for more information: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/#copy-entities-in-an-azure-table-with-azcopy-preview-version-only.